# How to delete only exact matching word and exclude pattern with hyphen character in sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I know there are many sed posts in this community but I did do my due diligence to evaluate them but I none proved to be the solution, or at least I could not derive one from them.
I wrote a bash script for deleting resource record lines in our Nameserver zone files. Such as

```
smtp            IN      A       12.34.567.890
```

or

```
media           IN      CNAME   vertex-prd.looney.acme.global.
```

It works for most cases, however, during testing I found a case that I need to account for but have not been able to do so. Basically, if there is a hyphen in the Host Label name (host label is the data entries in the left-most column, so smtp, media, etc) then the sed command deletes it, even though I specify the argument without it.

My command, example using `smtp` as text string which is received from user input at the cli as an arg:

```
sed -ie "/\bsmtp\b.*A\|A.*\bsmtp\b/d" "exampledomain.com.zonefile"
```

I also use an awk command to delete wildcard records:

```
awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '!(/*/ && /A/ && /'"78.89.56.90"'/)' "exampledomain.com.zonefile"
```

I have tried manipulating this command with `\< \>` to mark the edge of a word or `^$`, but not working. I have not tried using awk with `match` because I am not at that skill level yet.

How it is used:

`-a` is for A records, `-c` is for CNAME records. The second position is the option arg which is the text that is searched for to pattern match in the sed or awk commands, the third position is the name of the domain zone file which is the input file: `./my_script -a smtp sampledomainzone.com` or `./my_script -c media sampledomainzone.com`

A set of lines I am running it against:

Fragment from sampledomainzone.com:

```
smtp            IN      A       67.79.4.187
smtp5           IN      A       64.132.0.84
1smtp           IN      A       324.175.85.89
devsmtp         IN      A       67.79.4.187
test-smtp       IN      A        67.79.4.187
smtp-dev        IN      A       38.74.745.33
dev-media       IN      CNAME   vertex-bogus.looney.acme.global.
media-dev       IN      CNAME   vertex-bogus.looney.acme.global.
1media          IN      CNAME   vertex-bogus.looney.acme.global.
media           IN      CNAME   vertex-bogus.looney.acme.global.
```

Actual results:

```
...
smtp5           IN      A       64.132.0.84
1smtp           IN      A       324.175.85.89
devsmtp         IN      A       67.79.4.187
...
```

Or with `media` as arg:

```
...
1media           IN      CNAME  vertex-prd.looney.acme.global.
...
```

Expected:

```
smtp5           IN      A       64.132.0.84
1smtp           IN      A       324.175.85.89
devsmtp         IN      A       67.79.4.187
test-smtp        IN      A        67.79.4.187
smtp-dev        IN      A       38.74.745.33
```

Or

```
dev-media       IN      CNAME   vertex-prd.looney.acme.global.
media-dev       IN      CNAME   vertex-prd.looney.acme.global.
1media           IN      CNAME  vertex-prd.looney.acme.global.
```

My sed command deletes the `smtp` or `media` line, BUT also deletes any line with a hyphen `-` in it. The other lines that have those strings are not removed, as intended, but because they do not have the hyphen in them they are safe.

What I have tried:

Using sed with `\B` to match non-word chars, in addition to word boundary matching with `\b` in my command.

Using `[^-]*` in my command.

Using awk instead, like so:

```
awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '!(/\<'"${HOSTLABEL}"'\>/ && /A/)' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"
```

or

```
awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '!(/^'"${HOSTLABEL}"'$/ && /A/)' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: what command do we run to replicate your output from your input?

Comment: @jhnc Since I am using vars in my command to hold the cli args, if I remove them I think it would just be like this: `sed -ie "/\bsmtp\b.*A\|A.*\bsmtp\b/d" "sampledomainzonefile.com"`

Comment: why do you think `\bsmtp\b.*A` in sed should not match `smtp-dev IN A`? What do you think `.*` can match?

Comment: I am not that knowledgeable. Just need it to be an exact match of smtp, which works to an extent as it does not delete the lines with `smtp5` or `devsmtp` as examples. But the ones with hyphens like `smtp-dev` get deleted, even though that is not an exact match for `smtp A`.

Comment: what does `\b` match? what does `.*` match?

Comment: So `.* ` denotes any zero or more chars. But then why does it not delete `devsmtp` or `1smtp` but does delete `test-smtp`? Do I need to delimit escape the hyphen or something in order to only have `smtp` lines that match exactly deleted?

Comment: What does `\b` do? hint: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regular-expression-extensions

Comment: `\b`  matches a word boundary; that is it matches if the character to the left is a “word” character and the character to the right is a “non-word” character, or vice-versa. So before I was using that it would delete all lines that had `smtp` string in it. Once I included `\b` it improved on strictness by not deleting lines that have smtp in it with some other string. But this does not solve the problem of a line with smtp in it that has a hyphen to the left or right of it.

Comment: Yes, I have the gnu sed manual up and have been going over it, but so far my attempts have failed.

Comment: is a hyphen a word character? Does `.` match it?

Comment: Hyphen is not a word character. I did try with `\B` in place of `\b`, but it did not work. Maybe I did something wrong. I can test again. Or do I just include `\W` somewhere before or after the `\b`?

Comment: if you only want it to match "whitespace" `IN` "whitespace", why not specify that? eg. `^${label}[[:space:]]\{1,\}IN[[:space:]]\{1,\}A`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion: `sed -ie "/\b${HOSTLABEL}\bA\|A\b${HOSTLABEL}\b/d" "$DOMAINZONEFILE"` by removing the dot star so that it does include the dash symbol, but now not even the smtp line was touched.

Comment: I apologize, I do not understand your command, although I understand your logic and it is what I am trying to adhere to. I did try to implement it just now, but it does not work on my end.

Comment: Actually it worked. Thanks. What are the double square brackets for? Not seeing it in the manual yet.

Comment: `[:space:]` is a [character class](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)

Comment: Last question, what is the purpose of `{1,\}`. Or what section what that be described in the sed manual? The only thing I can find on it in the manual so far is for command grouping. But that does not look like the reason why it is in this command.

Comment: Found it, `\{i,\}`
Matches more than or equal to i sequences.

Comment: It declares an interval. See [paragraph 5](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06)

Comment: If you have an `awk` with in-place capability why not using it? `awk -i inplace '$1!="'"$HOSTLABEL"'"' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`. Or, more specific, `awk -i inplace '$1!="'"$HOSTLABEL"'" || $2!="IN" || $3!="A"' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`.

Comment: Since you want to delete **whole** lines, `grep` seems to be more appropriate. However, I don't understand the _arguments_ you are talking about. The only parameters in your examples are the variables HOSTLABEL and DOMAINZONEFILE. Perhaps it would help if you specify exactly the input to your script, and the intended behaviour.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I did not use awk inplace as you described in your examples provided because I am just now learning awk. The thing with awk is that it can be daunting the amount of approaches available one can take to achieve the same result. Like using parentheses for regex grouping vs not using them at all as you show in your samples, both being used to delete a line pattern.

Comment: @user1934428 I edited my post to specify things more exactly for input. I think my intended behavior is clearly stated. Should be more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: @humbleStrength The interesting aspect of `awk`, for your specific problem, is that it naturally splits the lines in fields, and the default field separators are strings of one or more white spaces. So, in your case, the host label is the first field (`$1`), the class is the second field (`$2`), the type is the third field (`$3`), etc. No need to split the line yourself, no need for regular expressions, you just compare the fields for equality with string values (e.g., `$2 == "IN"`).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet You expanded my knowledge with awk. I implemented this and it appears to work as intended. Using the default field separators being that in zone files they are white spaces, doing this with awk is more straightforward and simple than relying on regex and manual line splitting with sed. I will add this to the solution as an alternative.

Comment: While some of your exposition (i.e. lots of details) in your question are useful, you may find that posing questions in the form of `printf "GoodLine\nBadLine\n" | sed '/BADLINE/d'` will help you focus your problem AND get you faster ahswers. I DO however salute your persistence and desire to learn and improve your skills. Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your thoughts on this. I will definitely consider how I present my problems in the future on here for better focus/quicker responses

Answer (score 1):

As per my discourse with jhnc in the comments, the answer was to approach the problem with a different sed command specification entirely.

`sed -ie "/^${HOSTLABEL}[[:space:]]\{1,\}IN[[:space:]]\{1,\}A/d" "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`

Without the var expansion I am using:

`sed -ie "/^smtp[[:space:]]\{1,\}IN[[:space:]]\{1,\}A/d" "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`

Learned that using `\{i,\}` "matches more than or equal to i sequences", or "interval expression of the format "{m}", "{m,}", or "{m,n}", together with that interval expression it shall match what repeated consecutive occurrences of the BRE would match". In my case, a single occurrence to ensure minimal blast radius.

Also character classes and bracket expressions are immensely useful for conciseness and readability, such as `[:alnum:]` being equivalent to `[0-9A-Za-z]`

UPDATE:

As per user Renaud, an alternative that can be considered simpler or straightforward is using awk without doing regex or any manual line splitting: `awk -i inplace '$1!="'"$HOSTLABEL"'" || $2!="IN" || $3!="A"' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`. This applies to my case easily because in BIND zone file formats there is white space between the data columns and can be used as the field separators for the line splitting by default, at least this what I have come to understand.

Comment: And here is a useful web tool for testing your sed commands: https://sed.js.org/

Comment: If you have GNU `sed` you can simplify (and guarantee that `A` is really a full word): `sed -iE '/^'"$HOSTLABEL"'\s+IN\s+A\s/d' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet `\+` is not portable (eg. BSD-ish versions won't accept it). You can probably use `+` with a version that understands `-E` or `-r`. There aren't many [record types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) that start `A` but, yes, definitely worth appending the whitespace to exclude them.

Comment: @jhnc You're right, there are still some `sed` utilities that don't support extended regular expressions and POSIX still does not impose their support for `sed`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the insightful expertise. I will do my best to consider the probable outcomes and use the most appropriate command.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet So to assert in a sense that the type of DNS resource record is say only IPv4 with an A, and not AAAA for IPv6,  I should implement the `+`  with extended regex?

Comment: @humbleStrength No, `+` is just a shorthand for `{1,}`. So, use it or not, depending on the utility you use (and your portability constraints). Distinguishing the `A` and `AAAA` types is a different matter. `[[:space:]]{1,}A` matches `_A_` and `_AAAA_` (`_` for space) but `[[:space:]]{1,}A[[:space:]]` matches only `_A_`. So, prefer the latter. If your utility supports extended regular expression you can use the equivalent but shorter `[[:space:]]+A[[:space:]]`. If your utility is GNU `sed` you can also benefit from its extensions: `\s+A\s` (`\s` is GNU `sed` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`).

Comment: And note that, depending on the options you use, you may have to add backslashes before `{`, `}` and `+` or not. With GNU `sed` and the `-E` option there are no backslashes.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I encountered a case that I did not account for: `vendor          300     IN A            12.56.78.910`. When there is a TTL value set after the host label column, the white space field separation I think will not work. So the sed and awk methods that rely on white space between the patterns. So I would have to use an omission of some sort to look past, for the example in this comment, the `300`, and continue searching the line for the match.

Comment: I modified the awk field id to skip over the the 2nd field if  TTL is there: `awk -i inplace '$1!="'"$HOSTLABEL"'" || $3!="IN" || $4!="A"' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"` But obviously this will not work if there is no TTL value on the line. Have to figure out the command to handle both cases.

Comment: Simply use `NF`, the `awk` variable that contains the number of fields of the current line. Example: `awk -i inplace '$1!="'"$HOSTLABEL"'" || $(NF-1)!="IN" || $NF!="A"' "$DOMAINZONEFILE"`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I tried the awk with NF but neither `smtp` or  `smtp      300    ` lines where deleted. I am thinking I grep for a 3 digit field first to a var, check if it is not empty, then do an if and else, one for the command to delete smtp line without a TTL data field, and the other for a command with the TTL data field. I also tried this `sed -ie "/^${HOSTLABEL}[[:space:]][[:digit::]][[:space:]]{\{1,\}IN[[:space:]]\{1,\}A/d" "$DOMAINZONEFILE"` but that did not work.

Comment: I ended up doing a grep to get the line first, then a grep into awk '{ print NF }' to get the number of fields for that record line, then if else condition based on whether NF was greater than 4, as all record lines with custom TTL data are 5 NF, then just executed each awk command accordingly.